# Manage content type by admin menu link

Tags: nodes

I wants to manage content type by admin menu tab, suppose I am having a "news" content type and if I would go to put some news, then I have to go first "content" tab then "Add content option" would appear and after navigate it, it shows all content types where I would select news this is default Drupal functionality but I wants that there should be link in admin menu like news, so when I click on news it directly navigate to news content type page and there should be only news contents not all. So how to do that? Actually I am having a lot of content types that I wants to show, each content type by each admin menu tab and also shows the data particular for its.

Please tell every thing step by step.

Comment: finally, do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can install the [Administration menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module. Then you can navigate to your Content Types like this:

[image]

Or you can install the [Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module and create a block with the links to your Content Types like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it while creating or edit content type under Menu settings of that content type. Or you can create custom new menu from structure->menu, and put your add content url.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i don't wants to open content add page i just wants to open content listing page where all listing regarding content type.

suppose i created a menu named "news" when i click on news it should open a news content listing page having "Add news content" link on it and there will only "news" content not all and if you see in drupal content page it have all content types data in content page